# Авторизация в Google App Script

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Есть Web App приложение, написанное на Google App Script. Как БД используются таблицы Google. С недавних пор пропала авторизация.

"... Это приложение пыталось получить доступ к конфиденциальной информации в вашем аккаунте Google. Чтобы защитить ваши данные, мы заблокировали приложение доступ к ним. ..."

Пришлось создать Проект в Google Cloud Platform под это дело и указать его id в настройках скрипта. После этого авторизация прошла нормально. Но эта авторизация, которую я даю этому проекту на доступ к своим Sheets и Drive, стала коротко-живущей и слетает через определенное время.

Что нужно сделать, чтобы разрешения, которые я даю этому скрипту / проекту — не слетали?